# Policy to use the data in applications

Tags: discussion, support, policy, stackapps

I developed an extension for *Chrome* and *Opera*, but I'm not using the *Stackexchange API*, instead my extension accesses the page data http://stackexchange.com (using Ajax) and displays in the extension.

Features:

- Show pushs in toolbar (new score + new messages in inbox)
- Show inbox messages
- Show achievements data
- Don't save data (it just shows real-time *"stackexchange-button"* data)
- Don't modify pages
- Don't require *data* user authentication
- Don't use API

Does this infringe any Stack Exchange policy?

I intend to add this application on [StackApps](http://stackapps.com), [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) and [Opera Add-ons](https://addons.opera.com/en/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless all the data is pushed to some server so as you can maliciously retrieve users' inbox or something similar, nothing wrong with that - if Stack Exchange intends to keep one's inbox (or recent achievements, or mod messages, or whatever) in private (accessible by owner, mods or employees), and you don't break this rule, your app is legal.

Moreover, there are tons of such apps already. Also, I've made a script (which doesn't use SE api) which picks only declined/helpful/etc flags of your flag summary and displays them - but I don't publish the flag summary of anyone.

Comment: "*but I don't publish the flag summary of anyone*" Does this even matter if the data you collect is already public, and you have accreditation where required?

Comment: @James If the data *is* public, feel free to make scripts publishing it again. (just in case: [example of such script](https://goo.gl/MORAdB) by [1999](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259867/1999))

Comment: Thanks. Your application uses the API?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento *...script (which doesn't use SE api)...*

Comment: Because I was talking to one of the "employees of the SE", on Monday he said he will give an answer, so confirm with him accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Okay :)